# Azure MFA reset via SQL database

Tags: sql, powershell

Currently Resetting users via CSV but need to move that to a database.

I have tried my hand at converting the import to a SQL table and looping on a foreach but nothing outputs.

```
$dataSource = “servername”
$user = “dosname”
$pwd = $cloudcred
$database = “identityiqQA”
$connectionString = “Server=$dataSource;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd;Database=$database;Integrated Security=True;”
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$Result = $Dataset.Tables[0]
$Result


$MFAList = @();
Foreach ($Item in $Result) {
    $MFAList  | ForEach-Object {Reset-MsolStrongAuthenticationMethodByUpn -UserPrincipalName  $_.UserPrincipalName}
```

1. connect to the cloud and validate service account
2. import SQL
3. connect to database
4. run query in the script
5. loop a for each on the row provided
6. either remove the user from the row or throw a timestamp of when it was ran

Comment: For one thing, you should replace the curly 'smart-quotes' `“”` with straight ones.

Comment: I did after i uploaded it to the site and noticed that one.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a few steps in your code -  querying the database, creating the $Dataset object, and then loading the $Dataset object with the results of the query.

If you just want to retrieve one table in the MS SQL database, use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/read-sqltabledata?view=sqlserver-ps